# Passing generic func as Linq expression C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Linq expression that is repeating over multiple places. I want to centrally define the Linq expression and use it in all such places. Here is the code :

```
 public interface ISoftDelete
 {
    DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
 }

 public class BaseModel : ISoftDelete
 {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
 }

 public class Epic: BaseModel {
 }

 public class Feature: BaseModel {
 }

 public class UserStory: BaseModel {
 }

 public class ProductFocusDbContext : DbContext
 {
        public ProductFocusDbContext(DbContextOptions<ProductFocusDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

        public DbSet<Epic> Epics { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserStory> UserStories { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {

            // Epic
            modelBuilder.Entity<Epic>().HasQueryFilter(ExcludeSoftDeleted);

            // Feature
            modelBuilder.Entity<Feature>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.DeletedOn == null);

            // User Story
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserStory>().HasQueryFilter(x => x.DeletedOn == null);

      }

       System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<ISoftDelete, bool>> ExcludeSoftDeleted = (x => x.DeletedOn == null) ;
}
```

I want to replace all occurrences of `x => x.DeletedOn == null` with ExcludeSoftDeleted, but I get following exception when I try do it using the above code:

> InvalidOperationException: The filter expression 'x => (x.DeletedOn ==
>   null)' specified for entity type 'Epic' is invalid. The expression
>   must accept a single parameter of type
>   'ProductFocus.Domain.Model.Epic', return bool, and may not contain
>   references to navigation properties.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: A [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: Ok I'll try to create a min. rep. example

Comment: I updated my question with a minimal reproducible example

Comment: It's not reproducible. I can't copy, paste, and compile, let alone run. Ideally I'd like to run it, but at the very least compile it. Please copy your code to a new Console App and get it to compile/run.

Comment: Thanks  @pinkfloydx33, this is what I tried and it worked. If you can spare some time to put it as an answer and also if  you can, please also explain a bit on why an Interface type did not work, and instead I had to use concrete Type to make a valid Linq expression. Thanks!

Comment: I've made some updates to the answer. I cleaned up/simplified  the extension method version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HasQueryFilter` is a generic method where the generic parameter `T` matches that of the previous call to `Entity<EntityType>`. You have no problem passing an expression *manually* as the appropriate types get used. However, the expression property you tried passing is of type `Expression<Func<ISoftDelete, bool>>` and there is no implicit conversion from `Expression<Func<EntityType, bool>>`, even if `EntityType` implements `ISoftDelete` (`Expression<>` is not covariant), which is why it does not work.

You can get around this by providing some helper classes that can return you the appropriate expression for your entity.

```
public static class SoftDeleteHelper<T> 
    where T: ISoftDelete // constrain generic type to interface 
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExcludeSoftDeleted 
        => (x => x.DeletedOn == null):
}
```

And then you can refer to this inside of your query filter:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Epic>().HasQueryFilter(SoftDeleteHelper<Epic>.ExcludeSoftDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Feature>().HasQueryFilter(SoftDeleteHelper<Feature>.ExcludeSoftDeleted);
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserStory>().HasQueryFilter(SoftDeleteHelper<UserStory>.ExcludeSoftDeleted);
}
```

The key here is that we've constrained the generic parameter to `ISoftDelete` which guarantees that the `DeletedOn` property exists on the entity type.

Alternatively you could define this as a method that returns your entity expression. This may be more suitable if you have other query filters that need to be constrained to different interfaces:

```
public static class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> ExcludeSoftDeleted<T>() 
        where T: ISoftDelete // constrained to interface
        => (x => x.DeletedOn == null);
}
```

Which can then be used like the following (note this is different from above and requires `()` as you are invoking a function that returns the expression and not referencing a property)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Epic>().HasQueryFilter(ExpressionHelper.ExcludeSoftDeleted<Epic>())
```

You could go a step further and write extension methods on `ModelBuilder` or `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` constrained to the generic type and omit the helper class altogether

```
public static class EntityBuilderExtensions
{
    // extension method on the main builder 
    public static EntityTypeBuilder<T> EntityWithSoftDelete<T>(
        this ModelBuilder builder) 
        where T: class, ISoftDelete // extra class constraint required by Entity<>
    {
        return builder.Entity<T>().WithSoftDelete();
    }
    // extension method on the result of Entity<T>
    public static EntityTypeBuilder<T> WithSoftDelete<T>(
        this EntityTypeBuilder<T> builder) 
        where T: class, ISoftDelete // extra class constraint required by Entity<>
    {
        return builder.HasQueryFilter(
            e => e.DeletedOn == null 
        );
    } 
}
```

This works once again thanks to the generic constraint on `ISoftDelete`. You can then call them like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Epic>().WithSoftDelete();
    // or
    modelBuilder.EntityWithSoftDelete<Feature>();
}
```

The methods return an `EntityTypeBuilder<T>` which you can then use to chain further entity configurations.